# Different timeout interval for only one request

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, request, afnetworking

I'm trying to implement an API call with AFNetworking which will have a specific `timeoutInterval` (different than others in the session).

Currently, the app is using `AFHTTPSessionManager` to create API calls and default `timeoutInterval` is set to 60 seconds.
I would like to change the time interval only for one request (not for the whole session), so I'm asking if this is possible?